# Why higher plants lack centrioles?

Tags: cell-biology, botany

Why do plant cells not have centrioles?

Comment: Not related to the question, but just an explanation to whoever voted this as *too broad*: "too broad" doesn't mean that the possible answer is somehow opinion-based or hypothetical. *Too broad* means that OP is making several questions at once. From the text of the option: *"Please edit the question to limit it to **a specific problem**. Avoid asking **multiple distinct questions** at once"*. This may be closed, but not because it's *too broad*. I'll delete this comment soon.